# Is there a way to block notifications and reputation updates from specific sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, notifications, userscript

When I'm at work or engrossed in a technical site, I generally don't like getting distracted by notifications or reputation updates from sites like Meta SE and other recreational SE sites. Is there a way to block such notifications and reputation updates from showing up in the overhead bar, site-wise? Something like a user script might help too.

Comment: Or you can log out :)

Comment: @Joseph That wouldn't help. If I log out, I can't continue working on the technical sites. The global inbox for all sites is annoying.

Comment: you can also cross-post a userscript request on StackApps I believe (or is that not a thing anymore?)

Comment: Or simply, like, ignore or not follow any such notifications?

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica I could certainly do that, but it doesn't make it any less annoying.

Comment: @user1306322 I never posted any script-request on StackApps. That might work. Thanks.

Comment: @S.D. - If you go to your `Edit profile and settings > Preferences > Navigation`, there is the _Disable top bar stickiness_ which removes the top bar from showing if you scroll down. Of course this means you would have to scroll down each time when you look at an SE page but I guess it's a fairly simple workaround.